# How to fix the character encoding produced by jaggery-js?

Tags: javascript, wso2, jaggery-js

How to fix the character encoding problem produced by jaggery-js?

```html
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
   <% print('á, ú, č, š') %>
   <p>ı, ü, ğ, ö , ç , ş , İ</p>
  </body>
  </html>
```

output:

Ã¡, Ãº, Ä, Å¡

Ä±, Ã¼, Ä, Ã¶ , Ã§ , Å , Ä°

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/wso2/jaggery/issues/1) for this on the project's Github repository, which has been open since August 2012. There are a few things on there you could try.

Comment: it has a motto like "The delicious Javascript framework.", but it lose when it comes to taste!